# Excel python openpyxl methods

Tags: python, excel

Python excel methods doesn't work correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook


path = "C:\\My files\\Staff\\xProject\\ProjektExcelPython\\test_files\\"

spreadsheet_file = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, "PlikExcelDoKonwersji.xlsx"), engine='openpyxl', header = 1)

print(spreadsheet_file)
```

It works perfectly, but if I would like to use methods from openpyxl I have error.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook


path = "C:\\My files\\Staff\\xProject\\ProjektExcelPython\\test_files\\"

spreadsheet_file = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, "PlikExcelDoKonwersji.xlsx"), engine='openpyxl', header = 1)

#sheet = spreadsheet_file.sheet_by_name('sheet')
book = load_workbook(path, "PlikExcelDoKonwersji.xlsx")
sheet = book['SendMail1']
data = []

for row in sheet.rows:
    print(row[1].value)
```

Error:

```
line 94, in _validate_archive
    raise InvalidFileException(msg)
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support  file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`load_workbook` function only takes a single argument for file-path.
try

```
book = load_workbook(os.path.join(path, "PlikExcelDoKonwersji.xlsx"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the path 2 values, make it 1.
For Example, Try:

```python
book = load_workbook("C:\\My files\\Staff\\xProject\\ProjektExcelPython\\test_files\\PlikExcelDoKonwersji.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys it works but now another problem occurs.

I would like to start as before without first row, I used header = 1, but now it doesn't work I go for documentation.

```
def load_workbook(filename, read_only=False, keep_vba=KEEP_VBA,
                  data_only=False, keep_links=True):
```

So it isn't there. How you manage it in openpyxl?

I would like to make something like:

Find name in column[1], the same will be in column[2] and get one of data from row[7] using column[1] and column[2].

Thanks for any suggestions.